# Compare two Dataframe columns and retrive the mismatched columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 `dataframe` that need to be compare and return in which row the data mismatch happen, in which column the mismatch happen and what is present value and expected value need to what.

Both the `dataframe` contain these columns ID, Name, Location, Program

Need output in this format:

```
Mismatched Rows: (Row 2, columns=[channelName,sublobName]),(Row 3, columns=[sublobName])
```

Used code:

```
df_actual = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                       'lobName': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
                       'sublobName': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'],
                       'channelName': ['C1', 'C5', 'C3'],
                       'value1': [1, 2, 3]})
df_rpt_all1 = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                             'lobName': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
                             'sublobName': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'],
                             'channelName': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                             'value1': [1, 2, 6]})

merged_df = df_rpt_all1.merge(df_actual, how='left', on=['ID','Name','Location','Program'], indicator=True)

mismatched_info = []
for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    if row['_merge'] == 'left_only':
        non_matching_cols = []
        non_matching_vals = []
        for col in merged_df.columns:
            if col.endswith('_x') and row[col] != row[col.replace('_x', '_y')]:
                non_matching_cols.append(col)
                non_matching_vals.append(row[col])
        mismatched_info.append(f"(Row {index + 1}, columns={non_matching_cols}, values={dict(zip(non_matching_cols, non_matching_vals))})")

if mismatched_info:
    result = '\n'.join(mismatched_info)
    print(f"Mismatched Rows:\n{result}")
else:
    print("No mismatches found.")
```

Comment: show example data and expected result.

Comment: I have added the example as well as the output format.

Answer (score 1):

First we can find coordinates that are different in the dataframe

```
difference_df = df_actual  != df_rpt_all1
```

Then we can write a function that checks in a given row which columns are mismatching

```
def filter_different_columns(x):
    x= dict(x)
    index = x.pop('index')
    mismatched = [i for i in x if x[i]]
    return f"(Row {index}, columns=[" + ",".join(mismatched) + "])," if mismatched else ""
```

Then we use df.apply to apply this function to the dataframe

```
mimatched_data = difference_df.reset_index().apply(filter_different_columns,axis=1).sum()[:-1]

print(mimathced_data)
(Row 1, columns=[channelName]),(Row 2, columns=[value1])
```

Comment: df_rpt_all1 act as a lookup table it only conatins few rows where as df_Actual will contain 1000+ record , ```difference_df = df_actual  != df_rpt_all1``` it won't work in this case.

Comment: So you want to check if the entry in the actual table is part of column in lookup table or not?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert everything to dictionaries with coordinates. Then check on each coordinate if there is a mismatch:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df_actual = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                       'lobName': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
                       'sublobName': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'],
                       'channelName': ['C1', 'C5', 'C3'],
                       'value1': [1, 2, 3]})
df_rpt_all1 = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                             'lobName': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
                             'sublobName': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'],
                             'channelName': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                             'value1': [1, 2, 6]})

# convert to dict
d1 = df_actual.to_dict()
d2 = df_rpt_all1.to_dict()

dd1 = {}
# get coords per dict:
for key, value in d1.items():
    for i, v in enumerate(value.values()):
        dd1[(key, i)] = v

dd2 = {}
for key, value in d2.items():
    for i, v in enumerate(value.values()):
        dd2[(key, i)] = v
    
res = defaultdict(list)
for key in dd1.keys():
    if dd1[key] != dd2[key]:
        res[key[-1]].append(key[0])

mismatched_info = ','.join([f'(Row {k}, columns={v})' for k, v in res.items()])
mismatched_info = f"Mismatched rows: {mismatched_info}"
print(mismatched_info)
>>> Mismatched rows: (Row 1, columns=['channelName']),(Row 2, columns=['value1'])
```

Note that you can do more fancy stuf, for example first check if each dataframe has the same coordinates.

Your expected output does not make sense based on the input, the rows you mention are equal in both dataframes.

Edit: The sole purpose of this answer is to show you what is possible, a good implementation where you test the input and maybe use functions for repetitive tasks is up to you, the way you plan in implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df_actual = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                       'lobName': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
                       'sublobName': ['S1', 'S8', 'S3'],
                       'channelName': ['C1', 'C5', 'C3'],
                       'value1': [1, 2, 3]})

df_actual = df_actual.assign(ID = [1,2,3],
                             Name='name',
                             Location='loc',
                             Program='prog')
df_rpt_all1 = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                             'lobName': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
                             'sublobName': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'],
                             'channelName': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                             'value1': [1, 2, 6]})

df_rpt_all1 = df_rpt_all1.assign(ID = [1,2,3],
                             Name='name',
                             Location='loc',
                             Program='prog')
```

Use [`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for original indeces, last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df_rpt_all1.set_index(['ID','Name','Location','Program'])
                  .compare(df_actual.set_index(['ID','Name','Location','Program']),
                          keep_shape=True)
                  .set_index(df_rpt_all1.index)
                  .stack(0)
                  .rename_axis(['row','col'])
                  .reset_index()
                )
print (df)
   row          col other self
0    1  channelName    C5   C2
1    1   sublobName    S8   S2
2    2       value1   3.0  6.0
```

If need print output use:

```
if not df.empty:
    out='\n'.join(f"(Row {row.row}, columns={row.col}, values={ {row.self : row.other}})" 
                    for row in df.itertuples())
               
    print(f"Mismatched Rows:\n{out}")          
else:
    print("No mismatches found.")             

Mismatched Rows:
(Row 1, columns=channelName, values={'C2': 'C5'})
(Row 1, columns=sublobName, values={'S2': 'S8'})
(Row 2, columns=value1, values={6.0: 3.0})
```